How to show $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=O_p(\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{nh}}+h^2)$ when the kernel $K(\cdot) $ is of bounded variation?

Consider the kernel estimate $f_n$ of a real univariate density defined by $$f_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(nh)^{-1}K\left\{h^{-1}(x-X_i)\right\}$$
where $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed from $f, ~K$ is a kernel function and $h(n)$ is a bandwidth.
Regularity Conditions:
$\textbf{(a)}.$ We assume that $X_1, . . . ,X_n$ are independent and identically
distributed from a pdf $f (·)$ with compact support $[a,b].$In addition, $f$ is twice continuously differentiable and is bounded away from $0$ on its support.
$\textbf{(b)}.$ The kernel function $K(·)$ is a symmetric density function
about $0$ and has bounded variation. Moreover,
$\sup_{u} K(u)\le M <\infty$ for a constant $M$.
$\textbf{(c)}.$ The bandwidth satisfies $h\rightarrow 0$ and $nh\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty $.
Show that
$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=O_p\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{nh}}+h^2\right).$

Nonparametric Econometrics Li and Racine, 2006, Theorem 1.4. required Lipschitz condition on  $K(·)$ which stronger than bounded variation. Lipschitz assumption excludes, however, the uniform kernel.
How to get the same conclusion when $K(\cdot)$ has bounded variation?
